# Storing p-values from multiple 2 sample t-tests in R

Tags: r, for-loop, p-value, t-test

Good evening,
I'm working on a class project and I am trying to do multiple unpaired 2 sample t-tests and then storing their p-values so that I can work with just the p-values later
Below is the code I have been trying:

```
pVals_1Beta <-vector("numeric", length = nrow(group1_Y_Beta))

for (i in 1:nrow(group1_Y_Beta)) {
pVals_1Beta[i] <- t.test(x = group1_Y_Beta$values[i,], 
                         y = group1_N_Beta$values[i,], 
                         paired = FALSE, 
                         var.equal =FALSE, 
                         conf.level = 0.95)$p.value
}
```

where `group1_Y_Beta` and `group1_N_Beta` have two columns(`values` and `ind`) and about 110312 rows and I want to do run unpaired t-test comparing the two groups values and store all 110312 p-values. When I try running this I get:

> Error in group1_Y_Beta$values[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Any help on how to tweak my code to get it to work would be greatly appreciated.

THanks, LIz

Answer (score 0):

Since `group1_N_Beta` and `group1_Y_Beta` are 2D objects, you need (1) row and (2) column identifier in order to obtain a specific cell's value. But since you already specified the name of the column using the `$` notation, you only need to provide one number (or a vector of numbers) to complete the query. Replace `[i,]` ("ith row, all columns") with `[i]`

Comment: Thank you  so much for responding so i tried out your suggestion and am now getting the error:   
**Error in t.test.default(x = group1_Y_Beta$values[i], y = group1_N_Beta$values[i],  : 
  not enough 'x' observations**

Comment: What's the size of each vector? You can find that out by passing the name of the vector (`group1_Y_Beta$values[i]`) to `length ()`

Comment: When I pass it through it returns **1**

Comment: Is it supposed to return **1** ?

Comment: It's not! It means you either have one observation only (not enough for a t-test), or it's something else (data-structure-wise). If you could update the original post with sample data, that would help greatly!